# Retrieve variable from one page to display on second page in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, session, get, rank

I have a "standings" table which ranks teams from 1-42 through a mysql query. What I am trying to do is retrieve the rank from the first page to display on each team's page via php. I was able to get this to work using a second GET method through the team.php link, but it just doesn't seem right having the rank in the url along with the team id.

Here is my current code on the standings page:

```
for($i = 0; $i < $rows; $i++) {
$result->data_seek($i);
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
$rank = $row[12];
$teamid = $row[0];

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td class='rank'>" . $rank . "</td>";
echo "<td class='left'><a href='team.php?team_id=$teamid&rank=$rank'>$row[1]</a></td>";
for($j = 2; $j < 11; $j++) echo "<td>$row[$j]</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
```

And then the individual team's page:

```
$teamid = $_GET['team_id'];
$rank = $_GET["rank"];
```

I then just echo the $rank variable to display that team's rank, which works fine. However, is there a better way to retrieve the rank variable without sending it through the href? So I could change this:

```
echo "<td class='left'><a href='team.php?team_id=$teamid&rank=$rank'>$row[1]</a></td>";
```

Back to:

```
echo "<td class='left'><a href='team.php?team_id=$teamid'>$row[1]</a></td>";
```

While retrieving the rank in a different way?

I should note I also attempted to use a SESSION variable to retrieve the rank from the first page. However, each user's page displays the rank of '42', as the for loop overwrites the SESSION variable until the last row. As shown below:

```
session_start();
for($i = 0; $i < $rows; $i++) {
$result->data_seek($i);
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
$_SESSION["rank"] = $row[12];
$teamid = $row[0];

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td class='rank'>" . $_SESSION["rank"] . "</td>";
echo "<td class='left'><a href='team.php?team_id=$teamid'>$row[1]</a></td>";
for($j = 2; $j < 11; $j++) echo "<td>$row[$j]</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: You can just set a session variable

Comment: I've attempted to do so, but the variable displays the same rank "42" for every team on the team.php page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the way you tried is correct.. But, if you're still looking for an alternative, one method would be store each team rank in a separate session variable... something like `$_SESSION[$teamid] = $rank`;

```
for($i = 0; $i < $rows; $i++) {
$result->data_seek($i);
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
$rank = $row[12];
$teamid = $row[0];
$_SESSION[$teamid] = $rank;
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td class='rank'>" . $rank . "</td>";
echo "<td class='left'><a href='team.php?team_id=$teamid'>$row[1]</a></td>";
for($j = 2; $j < 11; $j++) echo "<td>$row[$j]</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
```

Then on you individual page you can try something like:

```
$teamid = $_GET['team_id'];
$rank = $_SESSION[$teamid];
```

Comment: Your alternative method is in the direction I was thinking. However, it doesn't return any data when I echo $rank.

Comment: are you setting `session_start()` at the beginning of both the pages??

Comment: Yes, and the sessions do communicate if I put some basic test data in.

Comment: I added quotations to $_SESSION['$teamid'] = $rank and it displays data. But it still returns "42" for each team's rank. So I believe the variable is still being overwritten each time the for loop runs.

Comment: the quotes you're adding is wrong..see my ans and add them as I did

Comment: Same result with the periods before and after variable name.

Comment: I couldn't replicate the problem the code works fine at my end

Comment: I switched from single quotations to double quotations and it worked! $rank = $_SESSION[".$teamid."] displays the correct ranking for each individual team. Thank you for your help Nishanth!